# Python Pandas sum with previous value whenever 0 is encountered in the column

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas column and I want to do a sum on it using the previous value when 0 is encountered in it. It will be more clear through this example -

```
ds = pd.DataFrame([0,1,2,3,4,50,0,1,3,5,55,0,5], columns = ['a'])

print(ds)

    a
0   0
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   50
6   0
7   1
8   3
9   5
10  55
11  0
12  5
```

Output should be -

```
    a
0   0
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   50
6   50
7   51
8   53
9   55
10  105
11  105
12  110
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with `shift` then `where` to mask all not 0 to `NaN` and then do `cumsum` , since you need the pervious fill value add again

```
df.a = df.a.add(df.a.shift().where(df.a.eq(0)).cumsum().ffill(),fill_value=0)
Out[132]: 
0       0.0
1       1.0
2       2.0
3       3.0
4       4.0
5      50.0
6      50.0
7      51.0
8      53.0
9      55.0
10    105.0
11    105.0
12    110.0
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

Comment: nice one, another method could be using `mask` - `ds.add(ds.mask(ds['a'].shift(-1).ne(0)).shift(1).cumsum().ffill().fillna(0))`

Answer (score 1):

One can exploit `.diff(-1)` to obtain the streak-ending location (50 and 55) directly:

- First, put `.diff(-1)` into `.where()` to retain the streak-ending elements while filling other elements with 0.
- Second, perform `cumsum()`, shift the result forward by 1 with `fill_value=0`, and add this to the original data.

Code:

```
ds["a"] += ds["a"].where(ds["a"].diff(-1) > 0, other=0).cumsum().shift(fill_value=0)
```

Result:

```
print(ds)
      a
0     0
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5    50
6    50
7    51
8    53
9    55
10  105
11  105
12  110
```